# TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'username' in pymysql

Tags: pymysql

I'm trying to access the database that I created with MySQL by using pymysql, but I got the error below. Does anyone have any ideas how to remove this error?

```
Connection = pymysql.connect(host="localhost",db="Student",port=8000,
username="makotonakai",passwd="password")

TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'username'
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

- Port 3306 is the default port for the classic MySQL protocol

```py
import pymysql

conn = pymysql.connect(
    host="127.0.0.1", port=8000, user="makotonakai", passwd="password", db="Student"
)

cursor = conn.cursor()
cursor.execute("SELECT VERSION()")

row = cursor.fetchone()
print("Server version:", row[0])

cursor.close()
conn.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

Change `username` to `user` and `passwd` to `password`. It should be

```
Connection = pymysql.connect(host="localhost",db="Student",port=8000,user="makotonakai",password="password")
```